# wget gets stuck on logging in as anonymus from ftp server

Tags: linux, networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, wget, rhel-7

I´m trying to download a file from ftp://ftp.perforce.com with wget. I´m using the following command:

wget -t 3 --timeout=10 ftp://ftp.perforce//path/to/file

I get the following output:

```
[xxxx@xxxxxx~]$ wget -t 3 --timeout=10 ftp://ftp.perforce.com/r20.1                                     /bin.linux26x86_64/p4api-glibc2.12-openssl1.0.2.tgz
   --2021-07-17 10:21:10--  ftp://ftp.perforce.com/r20.1/bin.linux26x86_64/p4api-gl                                     
    ibc2.12-openssl1.0.2.tgz
               => ‘p4api-glibc2.12-openssl1.0.2.tgz.1’
Resolving ftp.perforce.com (ftp.perforce.com)... 54.177.106.77
Connecting to ftp.perforce.com (ftp.perforce.com)|54.177.106.77|:21... connected                       .
Logging in as anonymous ...
Error in server response, closing control connection.
Retrying.
```

Increasing the timeout doesn´t help. Pinging the address + port 21 with nmap gives the following
output:

```
[xxx@xxxx~]$ nmap -p 21 ftp.perforce.com
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-17 10:24 CEST
Nmap scan report for ftp.perforce.com (54.177.106.77)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
rDNS record for 54.177.106.77: ec2-54-177-106-77.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.67 seconds
```

I´m using RHEL 7.9

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the actual server configuration + which users are available/passwords set. The safest bet would be to add username+password to the command like f.e.:

wget -t 3 --timeout=10 ftp://username:password@ftp.perforce//path/to/file

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.
It came out that the port 21 was blocked for incoming packets.